# Copy entire row if cell value matches combobox item

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

What I try to achieve is the following:

I have the following userform: 
[image: Userform lay-out]

The items in the combobox have been added via the following code:

```
cbbAirline.List = Array("NAX", "VLG", "QTR")
```

Now I have to filter from the sheet based on the selections in the combobox. After the filter has been done, I have to copy the **entire** row to a new sheet.

I already tried the following code but it keeps saying me that nothing has been found:

```
Dim findmatch As Object
Dim lastcell As Integer

Set findmatch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FlightList").Range("J:J").Find( _
               What:=UserForm1.cbbAirline.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not findmatch Is Nothing Then
    lastcell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UserForm1.cbbAirline.Value). _
               Cells(100000, 7).End(xlUp).row 'here find a way to locate last cell in sheet that has your name.. 
                                               ' it keeps returning me 1 but other than that it works fine
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UserForm1.cbbAirline.Value).Range( _
      Cells(lastcell, 1), Cells(lastcell, 40)) = _
       Range(Cells(findmatch.row, 1), Cells(findmatch.row, 40)).Value
Else
    MsgBox "not found"
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: `Debug.Print UserForm2.ComboBox2.column(1)` and see what comes up... Shouldn't it just be `UserForm2.ComboBox2.Value`?

Comment: Changed it to Value and now I get the correct value back. However I now get an error: Subscript out of range

Comment: @Mand there's not a reason why your code shouldn't work. Are you sure the company code (three letters) is in the column A? As for your last error, that's because you're setting a sheet that doesn't exist (probably your box has value "Select..." in this moment)

Comment: The airline was in column J. Fixed that. Still getting the error. How do I remove that?

Comment: @Mand On what line is your error occuring?

Comment: @dwirony On this line: lastcell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UserForm1.cbbAirline.Value).Cells(100000, 7).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @mand then you must not have a sheet named NAX/VLG/QTR